# What is wrong with this solution to Path in Matrix Problem on geeksforgeeks?

Tags: java, matrix, dynamic-programming

Can you help me with this geeksforgeeks problem
Given a N X N  matrix Matrix[N][N] of positive integers.  There are only three possible moves from a cell Matrix[r][c].

1. Matrix[r+1][c]
2. Matrix[r+1][c-1]
3. Matrix[r+1][c+1]

Starting from any column in row 0, return the largest sum of any of the paths up to row N-1.

Link to question : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=271

Link to solution : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/R5iu3xwTAO

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t  =1;
        int n;
        int a[][];
        while(t-->0){
            n = 17;
            a = new int [n][n];
            int input[]={67,280,171,381,930,781,925,4,393,380,246,433,762,258,5,166,315,503,385,728,854,350,464,288,304,80,689,56,313,843,92,379,122,614,111,403,394,387,406,138,767,651,571,880,260,927,398,926,429,782,653,634,132,468,274,435,548,314,490,212,156,933,942,629,546,404,31,292,142,436,781,260,86,703,140,697,630,537,622,410,318,275,44,801,94,669,236,993,982,77,204,137,10,497,765,907,900,147,550,42,582,331,301,19,33,792,715,14,680,336,424,350,962,467,150,408,135,737,400,468,814,956,956,175,452,72,433,704,218,983,97,799,665,749,169,49,541,883,63,572,570,486,921,884,304,423,291,790,159,42,257,324,997,212,498,801,283,283,504,500,617,952,650,281,700,818,329,592,52,743,164,621,228,436,856,883,858,498,672,17,540,928,340,536,139,190,336,773,472,191,272,88,142,921,720,842,90,400,433,141,143,948,114,722,384,969,605,593,819,276,961,358,556,301,893,46,842,581,819,665,771,90,104,265,363,823,106,452,574,890,945,68,190,58,790,925,378,746,517,196,373,478,905,280,130,798,326,323,730,144,987,500,585,90,764,947,264,221,751,837,463,47,257,652,456,46,576,185,143,444,381,867,921,285,147,402,434,472,724,163,615,710,15,551,151,130,498,414,703};
            int k=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    a[i][j] = input[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            HashMap<String,Integer> h = new HashMap();
            int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE,ans=0;
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                ans=CostPath(a,0,i,h);
                if(ans>max)
                    max=ans;
            }
            System.out.println(ans);
        }

    }


    public static int CostPath(int a[][],int x,int y,HashMap<String,Integer>h){
        if(h.containsKey(x+","+y))
            return h.get(x+","+y);
        int r;
        if(x>=a.length || y>= a.length || x<0 || y<0 ){
            r= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        else if(x==a.length-1 ){
            r= a[x][y];
        }

        else{
            r= a[x][y]+Math.max(Math.max(CostPath(a,x+1,y,h),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h));
        }
        h.put(x+","+y,r);
        return r;
    }
}
```

This should give output 13785 but it gives 10689

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error, or incorrect solution, or something else?

Comment: did you learn Dynamic programming, if not look at LCS problem. Very similar idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make help easier please hard-code test data (instead of using scanner). Also include the expected result.

Comment: @skandigraun Yes, I get incorect output instead of 13785 I get 10689

Comment: @c0der made changes, hardcoded input

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I do know Dynamic Programming. Infact I used memorization technique in given solution

Comment: `r = a[x][y]+
     Math.max(Math.max(CostPath(a,x+1,y,h),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h));` is wrong. It should be `r = a[x][y]+
     Math.max(Math.max(CostPath(a,x+1,y,h),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)),CostPath(a,x+1,y+1,h));`.  It may not be the only error.

Comment: does the 2D-array is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two small mistakes in the code:

```
r = a[x][y]+ Math.max(Math.max(CostPath(a,x+1,y,h),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h));
```

is wrong (`CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)`is calculated twice) It should be:

```
r = a[x][y]+ Math.max(Math.max(CostPath(a,x+1,y,h),CostPath(a,x+1,y-1,h)),CostPath(a,x+1,y+1,h));
```

And this

```
System.out.println(ans);
```

should be changed to

```
System.out.println(max);
```

After making these two changes the output is correct. 
A side note: 
There is no need to add to the map paths of invalid x,y values. To prevent it and make the program more efficient change

```
r= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

to

```
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Dynamic Programming solution. Here no need to store a HashMap, even the path itself. Note; I deleted the path info, it was a 2D-Array to store where the max comes from.

As you can see there is no recursion here. If you look at the recursion, from the bottom, you will understand this code.

Note; with your input result is 13785.

```
import java.util.*;

public class path {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t  =1;
        int n;
        int values[][];

        while(t-->0){

            n = 17;
            values = new int [n][n];

            int input[]={67,280,171,381,930,781,925,4,393,380,246,433,762,258,5,166,315,503,385,728,854,350,464,288,304,80,689,56,313,843,92,379,122,614,111,403,394,387,406,138,767,651,571,880,260,927,398,926,429,782,653,634,132,468,274,435,548,314,490,212,156,933,942,629,546,404,31,292,142,436,781,260,86,703,140,697,630,537,622,410,318,275,44,801,94,669,236,993,982,77,204,137,10,497,765,907,900,147,550,42,582,331,301,19,33,792,715,14,680,336,424,350,962,467,150,408,135,737,400,468,814,956,956,175,452,72,433,704,218,983,97,799,665,749,169,49,541,883,63,572,570,486,921,884,304,423,291,790,159,42,257,324,997,212,498,801,283,283,504,500,617,952,650,281,700,818,329,592,52,743,164,621,228,436,856,883,858,498,672,17,540,928,340,536,139,190,336,773,472,191,272,88,142,921,720,842,90,400,433,141,143,948,114,722,384,969,605,593,819,276,961,358,556,301,893,46,842,581,819,665,771,90,104,265,363,823,106,452,574,890,945,68,190,58,790,925,378,746,517,196,373,478,905,280,130,798,326,323,730,144,987,500,585,90,764,947,264,221,751,837,463,47,257,652,456,46,576,185,143,444,381,867,921,285,147,402,434,472,724,163,615,710,15,551,151,130,498,414,703};
            int k=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    values[i][j] = input[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }

            for ( int r = n-2 ; r >=0 ; r-- ) {

                for ( int c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ ) {

                    if (c == 0) {
                        values[r][c] += Math.max(values[r+1][c], values[r+1][c+1]);

                    } else if (c == n-1) {
                        values[r][c] += Math.max(values[r+1][c], values[r+1][c-1]);
                    } else {
                        values[r][c] += Math.max(values[r+1][c], Math.max(values[r+1][c-1], values[r+1][c+1]));
                    }
                }
            }

            int max = values[0][0];

            for(int c = 1; c <= n-1 ; c++) 
                max = Math.max(max, values[0][c]);

            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `while(t-->0){` for ? Also as posted the output should be 13785

Comment: it is from the original code, I think it used for T test. I didn't delete. I know it posted as 13785, but i'm very sure, anyway, I'll check again.